# Create a VSTRING from a scalar variable without using eval

Tags: perl, type-conversion

I'm just curious, - is it even possible to create a v-string from a scalar variable without resorting to `eval`?

I. e., this works, but uses `eval`:

```
my $var = 'v1.2.3';
my $conversion = to_vstring_1($var);
# Prints "Version: 1.2.3, type: VSTRING"
printf("Version: %vd, type: %s\n", $conversion, ref \$conversion);

sub to_vstring_1 {
    my ($arg) = @_;

    $arg =~ tr/0-9.//cd;
    $arg = 'v' . $arg;

    return eval $arg;
}
```

These two variants also work, and do not use `eval`, but they print "SCALAR" instead of "VSTRING":

```
my $conversion_2 = to_vstring_2($var);
# Prints "Version: 1.2.3, type: SCALAR"
printf("Version: %vd, type: %s\n", $conversion_2, ref \$conversion_2);

my $conversion_3 = to_vstring_3($var);
# Prints "Version: 1.2.3, type: SCALAR"
printf("Version: %vd, type: %s\n", $conversion_3, ref \$conversion_3);

sub to_vstring_2 {
    my ($arg) = @_;

    $arg =~ tr/0-9.//cd;
    $arg = pack('U*', split(/\./, $arg));

    return $arg;
}

sub to_vstring_3 {
    my ($arg) = @_;

    $arg =~ tr/0-9.//cd;
    $arg =~ s/[._]?(\d+)/chr($1 & 0x0FFFF)/eg;

    return $arg;
}
```

So, is there a fourth way to do it?

Comment: Working with https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/version/lib/version.pod you cannot seem to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it even possible to create a v-string from a scalar variable without resorting to `eval`?

Yes, it is, but it's a pain and there's no good reason to.

You can write XS code that:

- parses your input string
- converts the numbers to their char equivalents
- assigns v-string magic to your scalar with a call to [`sv_magic`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#sv_magic)

However, this is exactly what the internal function `Perl_scan_vstring` in [toke.c](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.24.0/toke.c#L11391) does. Why reinvent the wheel?